# request with a condition for an having sum

Tags: php, mysql, case

Can I help me please ?

I'm looking for a syntax.

How can I set a specific column value.

For example I would like to "say" (write) in a SELECT request : if the column "mycolumn" is empty or null, the default value of this column is "1".

My initial request is :

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE ...

I tried :
SELECT *, case table1.mycolumn when IS NULL then 1 FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE ...
```

Best regards.

Comment: you can't do that with a SELECT * you will need to list the column names that you are retrieving, and look into MySQL's inbuilt ifnull()

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
select 
col1,
col2,
case when mycolumn is null or mycolumn = '' then 1 else mycolumn end as mycolumn
from table_name
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and if possible on http://www.sqlfiddle.com and post your expected result into the question from the given sample data.

Comment: Ok but as per the question it should set a column value to 1 while selecting the data if its null, but from the fiddle you have all the data in all columns, could you explain more on what result you are looking at from the same data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying ! I would like to make a sum of toto's period schooling. How many days, months or years passed at school to study ^^. If the value is 0000-00-00, I want it to be equal to "today"

Answer (score 0):

In `MSSQL` it will be:

```
ISNULL(table1.mycolumn, 1)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

In `MySQL`:

```
IFNULL(table1.mycolumn, 1)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull